# Windows server 2008 send [RST, ACK] packets while several clients ask for tcp connections at the same time(less than 5ms)

Tags: sockets, tcp

I have a **Java Socket Server** running on a **Windows Server 2008**.

When using a multi-threads client to send several **TCP** connections at the same time, the client always get the "**Errno 111 connection refused**" error after the establishment of the first connection.

Here's the capture trace of **Wireshark** (10.1.3.136 is the server, 10.34.10.132 is the client): [Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoUMa.png) and the specific red trace goes here:[Trace2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhftI.png)

So, what's the issue?

If I delay-launch the thread by more than 5ms, or use a centos as the server, the errors disapperar. No exceptions are found in the server trace file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have filled the backlog queue, whereupon Windows starts issuing resets to further incoming connection requests.

This could be because you specified a small backlog value, but the more likely cause is that your server is simply not accepting connections fast enough: your accept loop is fiddling around doing other things, such as DNS calls or even I/O with the client, all of which should be done in the client's thread. All the accept loop should do is accept sockets and start threads.

Comment: I find out the 'backlog' config of ServerSocket is 1....Change it, and it works. So If the backlog is filled, the server host like Windows will choose to reset the connection, not the server application?